# Subtask estimates auto summed in parent task

Tags: tasks, jira

In Jira, I have subtasks with estimates.

**Task X (0 hours)**

- Subtask A (4 hours)
- Subtask B (8 hours)
- Subtask C (10 hours)

When I view the parent task, the estimated time does not display the sum of the subtask estimates.

Is there any way to get these to auto populate?